# Add custom validation when table is loaded in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I have a table with few columns. I have to add validation based on first two columns. 
First column is "Model Number" and second is "Part Number". I am  using html table with "for:each". And data is uploaded through CSV. They only have "Model NUmber" in csv and it must match with "Part Number" else throgh error. When page is loaded, i have an input file button. "onChange" of input file i am reading records and making table view to true.

But when i try to read input fields for my validation its coming empty.
I guess table is not rendered yet. 
How can i add validation in this case?

My code is something like this.

```
uploadCSV() {
   this.uploadDocumentView = true;
   let csvData = this.readCSV(); // have csvData correclty.
   this.uploadedRecords = csvData;

   // need to do validation for part number. 
   // they only have model number in CSV. It must match with data base else 
   // throw error.
   // uploaded model number must match with part number 
   let allModelNumInputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('.modelNumber');

  //allModelNumInputs -->coming empty.i guess its not rendered in the UI yet.

  allModelNumInputs.forEach(element => {
    console.log('element.value::'+element.value);
  });
}

<lightning-input onchange={uploadCSV} otype="file" name="Upload" 
   accept=".csv" ></lightning-input>
<template if:true={uploadDocumentView}>
<template for:each={uploadedRecords} for:item='rec' for:index="index">
    // here i have input field for Model number and output for part number 
    <lightning-input class="modelNumber" data-item={index} value= 
       {rec.Model_Numnber__c}></lightning-input>

       <div>{rec.Part_Number__c}<div>
    ......
</template>
```

I tried different events of input file for my validation, but no luck. If possible i don't want to make extra component for this. 
Any help will be highly appropriated.

Thanks,
Manohar

Comment: try to add `if:true={upoadedRecords}` to `for:each` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderedCallback` as follows:

```
renderedCallback(){
    if (this.upoadedRecords) {
        this.upoadedRecords.forEach(element => {
            console.log("element => ", element.Model_Numnber__c, element.Part_Number__c);
        });
    }
}
```

This method is called everytime time the DOM is rerendered and DOM is rerendered when `api` or `track` variables change. So you can have some manual mechanism to check whether `upoadedRecords` are changed. For example you can have:

```
renderedCallback(){
    if (this.upoadedRecords && this.upoadedRecordsChanged) {
        this.upoadedRecords.forEach(element => {
            console.log("element => ", element.Model_Numnber__c, element.Part_Number__c);
        });
        this.upoadedRecordsChanged = false;
    }
}
```

`upoadedRecordsChanged` can be set to `true` in any method where `upoadedRecords` is getting updated

Comment: thank you @salesforce-sas once agian.